# Can't share pdf file from android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I 'Am trying to share a pdf file that exists on my phone from my application but it keeps giving me "Encountering problems reading the file" if I tried to share it using Microsoft Teams or "Unable to attach file"  if I used Gmail.

Here's my code.

```
File sharingFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/123.pdf");

if (sharingFile.exists()) {
    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    Uri outputPdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, TransferInformation.this.getPackageName() + ".provider", sharingFile);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputPdfUri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share PDF using.."));
}
```

And I have already added this to my Manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Did you read "exported" attribute of "provider" documentation?

Comment: Yes I did, what about it.

Comment: My guess is that you do not have read access to `sharingFile`. You do not have access to files in `Download/` that your app did not put there itself (on Android 11 and higher).